# prove by inductive step

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I have some problem to prove this statement by the Principle of mathematical Induction.

$$\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i} = 2^n.$$
So I begin with the base step. For $n=0$, 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{0} \binom{0}{i} = 2^0 =1.$$

Now could you help me to show the inductive step?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us how far you can get with the inductive step please.

Comment: I wanted to prove with the "n+1"

Comment: Are you sure you have your base step correct? Think about what the "sigma" notation means: how do you start at $1$ but plug in $0$?

Comment: yes I am sure about the basic step: $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{0}{0} =\frac{0!}{0!}= 2^0=1$

Comment: Each entry in Pascal's triangle gets added in to the next row twice.  Therefore the sum of the numbers in the next row is exactly twice as big.

Comment: Use that $\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom{n}{k}+\binom{n+1}{k-1}$

Comment: @VolodymyrFomenko That equality is wrong: try it with $\;n=4\;,\;\;k=2\;$ .

Comment: I know this is an inductive proof, but I want to offer some combinatorial intuition as to why this result holds. Note that $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to select $k$ ones in an $n$-digit binary string. There are $2^{n}$ such binary strings. So $\sum_{i=0}^{n} \binom{n}{i}$ covers all of the $2^{n}$ strings.

Answer (score 0):

Hints: under the agreement that $\;\binom nk=0\;$ if $\;k>n\;\;or\;\;k<0\;$ , we get

$$\begin{align}&\bullet\;\;\binom{n+1}{k}=\binom n{k-1}+\binom nk\\{}\\
&\bullet\;\;\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\binom{n+1}k=\sum_{k=0}^{n+1}\left[\binom n{k-1}+\binom nk\right]=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk+\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk=2^n+2^n=2^{n+1}\end{align}$$